# How to get nearest value of a hexadecimal value

Tags: php

I need to calculate a nearest value of hexadecimal value.
e.g. : if hex value is like this '#CCFF00' then I could get '#CCFF33' or #CCFF66....

Could any body help me, I tried a lot to get some solution, but could not find any exact detail, there are some example available but all are needed two color code..

Thank you in advanced

Comment: I.. what?! How is `CCFF33` or `CCFF66` the nearest value to `CCFF00`? `CCFF00` *is* a hexadecimal value? `CCFF01` or `CCFEFF` are technically *closest* to `CCFF00` without being that exact number? Is that what you mean? Do you mean "I have an array of colours and want to find out which one of them is closest to `CCFF00`"?

Comment: You do know hexadecimal is a numeration system just like decimal. So `CCFF00 + 33 = CCFF33`, right? Open calc and check it..

Comment: That seems to be colours, so you're saying that `rgb(204, 255, 51)` and `rgb(204, 255, 102)` are the nearest values of `rgb(204, 255, 0)` ?!?

Comment: @h2ooooooo: Actually I need to get closest color to #CCFF00, So that if user search by this color code I should be able to show them more option that is almost similar to what ever user has selected/entered the color code, I don't have any pre defined array for it.

Comment: @SarveshTiwari Well the colour that is most similar to the entered colour is the entered colour minus or plus 1?

Comment: Well if we add +-1 we will get most of time same color but different color code.

Comment: @SarveshTiwari Not really. `FF0000` is not the same colour as `FF0001`. It might look similar, but it's not the same colour. The way colour codes work is that it's split up. It goes RGB (red, green, blue) and is translated to decimal (R = `FF` = `255` = `100%`, G = `00` = `0` = `0%`, B = `01` = `1` = `0.39%`).

Comment: ..hence you calculate the percentage of each colour by `R% = (R / (R + G + B)) * 100`,  `G% = (G / (R + G + B)) * 100` and  `B% = (B / (R + G + B)) * 100`.  `FF0001` is `99.6093%` red (`(255 / (255 + 0 + 1)) * 100`), `0%` green (`(0 / (255 + 0 + 1)) * 100`) and `%0.3906` blue (`(1 / (255 + 0 + 1)) * 100`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to understand that [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) is a [numeral system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_system), just like decimal you use every day.
So if in decimal (base 10) `10 + 1 = 11` then in hexadecimal (base 16) `CCFF00 + 33 = CCFF33`.

In PHP you can work with numbers represented in hexadecimal:

`0xCCFF00 + 0x33`

The only issue remaining is that echoing the result of that sum automatically converts it to decimal. You need to format it using [dechex](https://www.php.net/dechex):

`echo dechex(0xCCFF00 + 0x33);`